# Android synchronize Bluetooth connection

Tags: android, bluetooth

I need to synchronize Bluetooth connection in Android device. For example, if device not connected then throw an exception in one flow (not with async methods).

I have a good example for the async method (it is working), but not sure how to do this with Sync method.

Comment: please, show some of your code for the async method you have mentioned.

Comment: I used this library: https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-BluetoothSPPLibrary

Comment: Anyone know how to manage my issue ?